# Can't start RMI server after stopping it

Tags: java, rmi

I'm having a problem restarting my RMI registry after it has been stopped:

```
import java.rmi.*;
import java.rmi.registry.*;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class CinemaServer
{
    private Registry registry;
    ClientImpl clientImple; //remote interface implemented class
    private static String title="Cinema Pvt Ltd";

    public CinemaServer() {
        try {
            clientImple = new ClientImpl();
            registry=LocateRegistry.createRegistry(3311);
            registry.rebind("RMI_INSTANCE", clientImple);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Can't Start RMI Server",title,JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }

    public void stopServer()
    {
        try {
            registry.unbind("RMI_INSTANCE");
            UnicastRemoteObject.unexportObject(clientImple, true);
        } catch (NotBoundException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Can't Stop Server",title,JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
}
```

1. I start the server with: `CinemaServer ser=new CinemaServer();`
2. And when I call `ser.stopServer();` it stops.
3. **But I cannot restart it**

I'm getting:

```
java.rmi.server.ExportException: internal error: ObjID already in use
at sun.rmi.transport.ObjectTable.putTarget(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.exportObject(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.exportObject(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.exportObject(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.transport.LiveRef.exportObject(Unknown Source)
...
```

Comment: Can you paste the error message that you receive? What happens when you try to restart?

Comment: i am getting "java.rmi.server.ExportException: internal error: ObjID already in use" error

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: @mikaveli, sorry but what is "stack trace"?

Comment: Very basically, it's the full error output of the exception you've encountered.

Comment: i am only getting "java.rmi.server.ExportException: internal error: ObjID already in use" error

Comment: Please replace all your `JOptionPane.show...` calls with `e.printStackTrace()`, and copy what you get on the console.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

the call is failing on `createRegistry()`, *not* on re-exporting your object.  don't create the registry twice.

Comment: ohhh how did i forget it?thank you @jtahlborn i solve with your help thanks once again